# cpplint.py & cmake: how to specify include files

Tags: c++, cmake, include-path, cpplint

Assume I have a project of the following directory structure:

```
myproject
├── .git [...]
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── foo.cc
    └── foo.h
```

If in `src/foo.cc` I include the header file like `#include "foo.h"` and then run Google's [cpplint.py](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint) on it, it complains with

```
src/foo.cc:8:  Include the directory when naming .h files  [build/include] [4]
```

So I include it as `#include "./foo.h"`. Now I get another complaint:

```
src/foo.cc:8:  src/foo.cc should include its header file src/foo.h  [build/include] [5]
```

However, if I include it as `#include "src/foo.h"`, the compiler won't find it, with my current setup of CMake. This is how my two CMakeLists.txt files look like:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(myproject)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SRCS foo.cc)
add_executable(foo ${SRCS})
```

Is the way I'm using CMake somehow fundamentally wrong? Should I remove the `src/CMakeLists.txt` file entirely, and specify all source files in the base `CMakeLists.txt` with their full path?

Or should I simply ignore cpplint's complaints, as they don't really fit to how CMake projects are to be set up?

Comment: What happens when you pass `--root=src` to cpplint.py?

Comment: I tried it, but strangely, it doesn't change anything. Also, I understand that cpplint.py treats the one directory containing the .git folder as base directory. It sounds reasonable to me, and I don't think I should overwrite it with the --root option.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes), Google expects you to add the `src` directory to your include path. You should probably put an `include_directories` call in one of your CMakeLists.

Comment: You mean putting `include_directories(../)` into the src/CMakeLists.txt? Hm, yes, that works for both, CMake and cpplint.py. It seems slightly awkward to me though. Nevertheless, thanks for your support! Put your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I guess it would be `.` from `src`, but you're right, it is a bit awkward. I've been digging some more, but I can't really find a definite source on how cpplint expects projects to be laid out: all of Google's own projects seem to do things differently: separate `include` directory or not, subdirs under `src` or not... Maybe someone else can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` in your top level CMakeLists.txt, like Wander suggested:

```
project(myproject)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Comment: The solution was to add `include_directories(.)` to the top level CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Yes Georg, your right...I meant to put `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})`